# Mash overflows and lid comes off distiller

Tags: distillation

I've got a store bought distiller, this is my second time using it.

The first time I put homemade wine & made some nice Brandy. This time I have a all-grain mash which has been fermenting for 5 days.

Once the distiller heats up enough the lid pops open & makes a huge mess. It also pours out the nozzle very quickly. It's supposed to drip slowly and the lid is supposed to stay on.

From my research it's possibly not done fermenting as it does seem very 'fizzy' (bubbly when shaken). However I am not 100% sure of the reason. Could I have put too much carbon in the nozzle?

Here's a picture of the still:
[image]

Can I pour the mash back in with the rest of my mash? (I have 23L of mash my distiller only has 4L)

Is there anyway I can 'debug' this / figure out why it's happening? It's happened twice and I'm scared to try a third time.

Comment: This is probably better directed to the homebrew SE site.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people refer to this as a "puke". It's like the distiller is puking.

**I managed to solve my problem** (Currently half way through the first batch ;-)). **I used a "distilling conditioner"** AKA defoaming agent purchased at my local brewery store

I also degassed the wort using a drill and a whisk, however this alone was not enough.

*Note: I didn't use any of the below advice, just leaving it here for completeness*

Other advice I've gotten on other forums includes clearing the wort better (E.g using cold temperature + time or a clearing agent), and putting a few rashing rings or stones inside the distiller as the airstill's inside may be too smooth.